# Sanitize input data php

Tags: php, regex, mysqli

I have a contact form in my website **[rexhin.al](http://rexhin.al)** where visitors can contact me. It has 3 fields only: name, phone number, and message.

This is my function for sanitizing input data which will be written in a database. I checked the [php manual](https://php.net/manual/en/index.php) and a few questions here at stackoverflow and I came to this solution.
Is this a safe way for sanitizing data?
Are the functions in the correct order?
Does the order really matter?

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    include '../classes/' . $class . '.class.php';
});

/*
    beje qe nqs ekziston ip bej update vtm time dhe ++$count te ajo ip;
*/

$db = DB::get_instance();   

function sanatize($input) {
    $db = DB::get_instance();
    //mysqli real escape string for all vars.
    //preg_replace for whitespaces, tabs, new lines.
    //strip html tags.
    //convert html tags.
    //strip slashes.
    //htmlentities: htmlentities — Convert all applicable characters to HTML entities.
    //nuk duhet sepse kemi strip tags.

    //trim string
    $trimed_string = trim($input);
    //filter string using php FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING filter.
    $filtered_string = filter_var($trimed_string, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    //remove slashes
    $no_slash_string = stripslashes($filtered_string);
    //convert special characters to HTML entities
    $conv_string = htmlspecialchars($no_slash_string);
    //strip html tags
    $stripped_tags_string = strip_tags($conv_string);
    //replace whitespaces
    $filtered_string = preg_replace('#[\s]+#', ' ', $stripped_tags_string);
    $safe_string = $mysqli_escaped_string = $db->mysqli->real_escape_string($filtered_string);

    return $safe_string;
}

//send message
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if(isset($_POST["name"]) && isset($_POST["tel"]) && isset($_POST["message"])) {

        $name = sanatize($_POST["name"]);
        $tel = intval(sanatize($_POST["tel"]));

        //sepse intval ja heq zeron.
        $message = trim(sanatize($_POST["message"]));
        $time = time();

        //name validation.      
        //only letter and spaces.
        if(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/', $name)) {
            echo "name should contain only letters.";
        } else if(strlen($_POST["name"]) < 3) {
            echo "name should be three chars min.";
        } else if(!preg_match('/^[1-9][0-9]*$/', $tel)) {
            echo "your phone number should contain only numbers.";
        } else if(strlen($tel) != 9) {
            echo "your phone number must be 10 digits.";
        } else if(in_array(substr($tel, 0, 3), array(066, 067, 068, 069))) {
            echo "your phone number must begin with 066, 067, 068 or 069.";
        } else if(strlen($message) == 0) {
            echo "message should be 10 letters min.";
        } else {
            //insert into db.
            $query = "insert into `messages` (name, tel, message, time) VALUES ('$name', '$tel', '$message', '$time')";
            $db->mysqli->query($query);
            echo "sent";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `\s` match any white space character `[\r\n\t\f ]`

Comment: Sanitizing, like escaping, should be context-specific. What are you trying to constrain your input to? "Safe" for what use specifically? And why aren't just you using mysqli bound parameters?

Comment: yes `\s` full-fill it.

Comment: Check my edited question @mario. I included my whole file.

Comment: The prior escaping then is kinda redundant if you validate the actual string formats afterwards anyway. The proper order for you sanitization function should have been `stripslashes`, `strip_tags`, `filter_var`,  `spaces`, `trim`, `htmlspecialchars` and then `real_escape_string` btw. One "super" escaping function for everything is usually not a good idea.

Comment: See also [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relevant bits are these:

```
filter_var($trimed_string, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$db->mysqli->real_escape_string($filtered_string);
```

Though one could argue that prepared statements are easier to use than manual escaping (thus less likely that you miss a field) this should be enough from the *input* point of view. Even lack of `filter_var()` wouldn't be specially bad if you took proper care of SQL injection.

But you also perform lots of edits on user data that are fairly misguided:

```
stripslashes($filtered_string);
htmlspecialchars($no_slash_string);
strip_tags($conv_string);
preg_replace('#[\s\t\n]+#', ' ', $stripped_tags_string);
```

I wouldn't consider a contact form reliable if I wasn't able to recover the exact input data provided by the user and you're basically removing arbitrary characters and corrupting data.

I think the root problem are a couple of misconceptions:

1. Data sanitisation as not an absolute. Whether a given piece of data is considered safe is entirely context sensitive. E.g., HTML tags are irrelevant in SQL.
2. You don't have to *remove* special characters in order to make them safe. You just need to handle them properly.